# javascript to css selector

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I would like to convert this javascript line of code to CSS, I've been searching the site and google but haven't got straight answer.

```
var riskCell20 = document.getElementById("risk.probablity.literal.l100").childNodes[2];
```

to something like

```
#risk.probablity.literal.l100:nth-child(2);
```

could not find the right syntax

Comment: Does that element has that ID of exactly that (with the periods)? Or are they classes? Your CSS string actually means selecting an element with ID `risk` with the classes `probability`, `literal`, `l100`

Comment: Can we assume this element's childNodes consists of only element nodes? Because usually it contains text nodes alongside element nodes, and given the kind of document you're working with it's very likely this element contains text nodes which would completely throw off the index.

Comment: it'd be `nth-child(3)` since the nodes are numbered from 0.

Comment: The is is the whole string, it is used just like java package naming

Comment: That was ibm RTC, we can not change it

Comment: I am working with a table and wanted to get specific column and row (cell). I do have a title associated with the table

Comment: @War10ck: I think the asker knows the difference. This is just an ID with a naming scheme consisting of periods similar to Java packages. No confusion there.

Answer (score 4):

As the `id` has dots, which is the character for target a class, you could use the attribute selector.

```
[attribute="value"]
```

With it you can target an element's attribute, such as `title`, `href`, etc., and in this case its `id`.

Stack snippet sample

```css
[id="risk.probablity.literal.l100"] :nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="risk.probablity.literal.l100">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

---

Note, the `nth-child` is not zero based, the `childNodes` is, so if you want the third child (`childNodes[2]`), your `nth-child` should be 3 (`nth-child(3)`)

Answer (score 1):

Since the `.` character has a special meaning on a selector, you may have to escape it:

```
#risk\.probablity\.literal\.l100:nth-child(2);
```